# NSPredicate to filter against a complete NSArray of strings, using nsstring

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I need to filter a multi nested json that is basically an array of dictionary containing values for key that are also arrays

Here is a sample

```
{//Upper structure, an nsaaray of responses
Items =     (
            {
        descriptionRating = "some";
        category = 20;
    }
);
 dynamicVales =     (
    {
        text = "name";
        value = "falafel";
        type = 3;
    },
    {
        text = "name";
        value =       (
           turkeysandwich, 
           burger, 
           snickers
        );
        type = 2;
    },
    {
    text = "name";
        value = "whatever";
        type = 2;
    },

  );
},
```

so I have an nsarray of responses, each response has an nsarray of nsdictionaries  in this case called "dynamicVales", this can contain one string or an array of strings, I need to filter all responses where a value in in dynamicVales = a string a value I have. That string is equal to the array

```
 NSString *selectedString = @"turkeysandwich, burger, snickers";
```

I tried this

```
[filteredresponses = self.responses filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSString 
 stringWithFormat:@"dynamicVales.value CONTAINS '%@'", selectedString];
```

obviously that is not working, is there a way of doing this in one predicate as opposed to me looping over these internal arrays?

```
   value =       (
           turkeysandwich, 
           burger, 
           snickers
        );
```

So in summary I need to filter that the entire contents of the string equal all contents of the NSArray in Value.

Comment: There's something confusing about your definition.  How can a dictionary that contained in an array be referred to by a name (dynamicValues)?  Are you sure you don't have an array of dictionaries which contain dictionaries?

Comment: Actually it is an NSArray, I am trying to filter based on whether an entire NSArray = Values

Answer (score 4):

For your problem try the following code.

```
NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ANY dynamicVales.value == 'chicken'"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
NSArray *filteredResults = [Mainarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

You can see more syntax for the Predicate the arrays or Dictionaries, you can learn lot from below link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1

Happy coding!

Comment: This is not doing the job,

Comment: definitely it will work i tried even with your given array @Huang

Comment: I am trying to compare a comma seperated string against the entire array, meaning I want to see whether dynamicVales.value ( which is an nsarray here ) equals   @"turkeysandwich, burger, snickers"

Answer (score 0):

You can use predicateWithBlock method for creating your predicate. Inside the block, check whether the dynamicVale contains the value to be searched.

Code:

```
NSArray *yourArray = ....;
NSString *searchText = ...;

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary   * _Nonnull evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {
    NSArray *dynamicVales = [evaluatedObject valueForKeyPath: @"dynamicVales.value"];
    return [dynamicVales containsObject:searchText];

}];

NSArray *filteredArray = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Hi, this is working for dynamicVales.value, assuming its a scalar value, meaning if I get

Comment: I guess what I am asking is , your solution assume value = searchtext, how can I make it to be value Contains searchtext, while still maintaining it as a block predeicate?

Comment: in such case you can use an inner predicate, filter the array and return filteredDynamicValues.count > 0

Comment: I thought the predicatewithblock is the inner predicate!!